# Get the number of bots in a server

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm making a public member count for my server, which will be displayed in the name of a locked voice channel on top of the channel list.

Though, to make the count even more accurate, I would like not to include the bots into the member count. I assume the best way to do that would be to subtract the number of bots from the total number of members in the server.

The thing is, I don't know how to get the number of bots in a server (only the total number of members).

Thank you all in advance :D

Comment: `Member.bot` will return `True` for all bot accounts. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`guild.members` returns the list of members of the guild, 
`member.bot` which has the attribute `bot` is `False` for user accounts.

Comment: @dan1st It doesn't, I've used it with a regular bot account (no gateway intent enabled).
You can get this data from the context / ctx object.

Answer (score 0):

Notice you will need to turn on member intents for your bot for this to work:

```py
@client.command()
async def bot_count(ctx):
    members = ctx.author.guild.members
    bot_count = 0
    for i in members:
        member = i.bot
        if member == True:
            bot_count += 1

    await ctx.send(f"Server has {bot_count} bots!")
```